# Representing Laravel model when the id of table A can be set in columns foo and bar of table B

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, foreign-keys, relationship

My model has `table A` and `table B`.

The `table B` contains two columns: `foo` and `bar`.

Both `foo` and `bar` contain a different `id` of `table A`.

How should it be represented in the model ?

Comment: Did you solved?

Comment: not yet, I've tried both solutions, but it doesn't return anything with php artisan tinker. I'm still digging into it.

Comment: I suppose you put inside of your rmodel definition: 

protected $table = 'TableA'; 

where TableA is the actual name of the table.

Comment: If you you do this?

$tableA = TableA:: all();

foreach($tableA as $t)
     dd($t->foo->id);
endforeach

you get nothing?

Comment: Or even better:

$tableA = TableA:: all();
foreach($tableA as $t)
   if (isset($t))
      dd($t->foo->id);
endforeach

because you will have tuples which will return NULL on foo and not NULL on bar and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make 2 haveMany relationships from Model A to Model B.

for Model A:

```
public  function foo(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\ModelB','foo','id');
}

public  function bar(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\ModelB','bar','id');
}
```

And ModelB will have to belongsTo relationships.

```
public function foo {

    return $this->belongsTo('App\ModelA','foo','id');
}
public function bar {

    return $this->belongsTo('App\ModelA','bar','id');
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks a lot!! I've just rewrited hasMany('App\ModelB','foo','id') to hasMany(B::class, 'foo').

Answer (score 0):

You can define the relationships by providing the keys as parameters to the eloquent methods.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

Something like this:

```
<?php

class TableB extends Model{
    // Get TableA from the TableB foo column
    public function tableAFromFoo(){
        $this->hasOne(TableA::class, 'id', 'foo');
    }

    // Get TableA from the TableB foo column
    public function tableAFromBar(){
        $this->hasOne(TableB::class, 'id', 'bar');
    }
}

class TableA extends Model{
    // Inverse of the relationships
    public function tableBUsingFoo(){
        $this->belongsTo(TableB::class, 'foo', 'id');
    }

    public function tableBUsingBar(){
        $this->belongsTo(TableB::class, 'bar', 'id');
    }
}

?>
```